# iOS development different user permissions get different features

Tags: ios

Can I have one app that changes depending on user permissions. For example if I were a paying user I would be able to login to the same app and ONLY be able to SEE and play tetris, however, if i were a free user i would login to a free account and ONLY be able to SEE and play pong. Essentially having two apps put into one and a person can choose between the two games by logging in or logging out. If so, how can I approach this?

edit: I have a custom TBC involved. Is it possible that it changes too depending on a user's permission?

edit2: Sorry... Also Would it make my app unreasonably big and slow? Since I would have so many more MVC objects (essentially at least twice the size since I would need to create an object for a subscriber and a freeuser?)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, all you need is to create and store some specific flag, for example isUserPremium and check it on the initial view controller or in AppDelegate. Than depending on it you can lead user to different view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in-app Purchase inside your app. You can put `Consumable In-App Purchase`. And then with `NSUserDefaults` value, you can show respective games to user. Eg, if their value is false then show pong game otherwise show tetris game. For more details on how to integrate in-app Purchases follow this [Raywenderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial)